# `alias_method` a private method

Tags: ruby, alias-method

I have a class that exposes two interface methods `client_options` and `user_options`, and at this ancestry level, they are equivalent to `default_options`. I don't want other developers to implement `default_options` directly, hence it's private.

```
class Foo
  def client_options
    default_options
  end
  def user_options
    default_options
  end

  private
    def default_options
      { foo: :bar }
    end
end
```

To save some lines of code, I wanted to alias the methods:

```
class Foo
  alias_method :client_options, :default_options
  alias_method :user_options, :default_options

  private
    def default_options
      { foo: :bar }
    end
end
```

but `alias_method` only aliases public methods.

I found how to alias private methods on [this blog](http://www.cgore.com/programming/ruby/public-aliases-of-private-methods.lisp):

```
class Foo
  def default_options
    { foo: :bar}
  end

  private :default_options
  alias_method :client_options, :default_options
  public :client_options
end
```

but, it's little bit unreadable.

Is there a more straight solution to alias a private method?

Comment: If I was to implement a `Foo` subclass, I would appreciate explicit method definitions. Using `alias_method` might save a line or two but it makes it more difficult to understand your class.

Comment: Seems to me that if I count the lines of code literally every answer is more lines (or at most 1 less) of simply writing the first public method as you have and aliasing the second.  As that's also more readable than any of the more complex suggestions why not just do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Alias, then privatize:

```
alias_method :client_options, :default_options
alias_method :user_options, :default_options
private :default_options
```

Or, whether you are so aware of this “scissors rule”:

```
%i(client_options user_options).each do |m|
  define_method m { default_options }
end
```

Or create your own `alias_method` alike method

```
  module AliasPrivateMethod
    def alias_private_method_to_interface(name, original_name)
      define_method(name) do |*args, &block|
        send(original_name, *args, &block)
      end
    end
  end

  class Foo
    extend AliasPrivateMethod
    alias_private_method_to_interface(:client_options, :default_options)
    private
      def default_options
        { foo: :bar }
      end
  end

  foo = Foo.new
  foo.public_methods(false) # => [:client_options]
  foo.client_options        # => { foo: :bar }
```

Comment: hi thank you for answer, but that's the same thing I've posted in the question

Comment: Really? Probably SO shows me the uglified version of the question, but I can not see that is posted. What´s wrong with this approach then?

Comment: it is a valid approach I'm not saying that It's just I was looking for a solution that would respect the "scissors rule" ....funny enough I cannot google any article on this rule but Robert C. Martin (creator Clean Coders videos) was talking about it. It's a rule from old days where you try to keep public methods / interface methods at the top of your code and private methods below. Ruby is well implementing this when  you stick private methods below the keyword `private` . So imagine if my class have more private methods they are below private, yet `default_options` must be above private.

Comment: Hope I make sence, I run of allowed comment size to explain it :)

Comment: @equivalent8 your last example doesn't respect this rule either.

Comment: you man the example in my Question or in the Answer ???   ... if you mean the example in Question ... yes exactly :)  that's why I posted this question because I thought there is some built in method like `alias_private_method` or something , but it looks like it's not :(

Comment: I fully agree this is a good solution but the thing is if a developer must  define `private` method then make it public again I guess it's just better if he delegates the method to self (like in my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31983509/473040)  just my opinion

Comment: just wrote an article explaining the scissors rule further if anyoune want to learn more about it http://www.eq8.eu/blogs/16-scissors-rule-in-coding

Answer (score 1):

One approach I find good alternative is to delegate the private method to `self`

```
require 'forwardable'
class Foo
  extend Forwardable
  def_delegator :self, :default_options, :client_options
  def_delegator :self, :default_options, :user_options

  private
    def default_options
      { foo: :bar }
    end
end

f = Foo.new
f.client_options 
# => { foo: :bar }
```

Answer (score 1):

What about implementing the method you want to hide in a prepended module?

```
module ProtoFoo
  protected
    def default_options
      {foo: :bar}
    end
end

class Foo
  prepend ProtoFoo
  def client_options; default_options end
  def user_options; default_options end
end
```

Even if a user overwrites `default_options` in `Foo`, it will not have effect.

If you insist on writing the hidden things after the exposed things, you can do:

```
class Foo
  def client_options; default_options end
  def user_options; default_options end
end

module ProtoFoo
  def default_options
    {foo: :bar}
  end
end
Foo.prepend ProtoFoo
```